# Formating content rendered from wordpress REST API as JSON and not HTML

Tags: rest-api, json

I am new to Wordpress and REST API and I need to read posts from /wp-json/wp/v2/posts with an external application called Intuiface.

Intuiface can interpret JSON but the content of the post is shown in html:

```
    "<p>Content</p>"
```

Is it possible for wordpress to format this as text and image links if there are images instead of HTML?

Comment: You could theoretically strip all the HTML from the content, but then you'd be removing all  line breaks and paragraphs. Ideally your application would parse the HTML into whichever format it needed. A quick search returned this: https://support.intuiface.com/hc/en-us/articles/360007179212-HTML-Frame-Asset. Is that any use?